# Webview html to host communication in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I am trying to wrap my head around establishing communication between an HTML page in a webview in Nashorn and the host nashorn application. I read this tutorial
[here](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/porting_from_the_browser_to)

but I can't seem to get how to create a callback which I can call inside the HTML page to run something in the host. The wrapping function works fine I just don't know where to go from here to get webview html to host communication. No matter how I do it, I get an empty object but no methods.

```
This.engine.loadWorker.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
changed: function(value, oldState, newState) {
  if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
    function testObj(){
      this.foo = function(){
        print('hello');
      }
    }
    This.document = wrap(This.engine.executeScript("document"));
    This.window = wrap(This.engine.executeScript("window"));
```

I tried

```
This.window.setMember('HOST',new testObj());
```

and

```
This.window.setMember('HOST',wrap(new testObj()));
```

Both get me nothing in the window

```
This.window.executeScript("window").setMember('HOST',new testObj());
```

Gets me an empty object in the HTML page javascript "{}"